# Batch file: Use Loop for in command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the program (exe form) that can read many params and I can run it as following command:

```
myprogram param1 param2 param3 etc
```

Now, I want to write a batch file command to call above command:

```
myprogram %1 %2 %3 %4
```

But you know, number of params is unlimited. So I want to use for loop in this situation. I tried

```
myprogram for %%x in (%*) echo %%x
```

But it didn't help me.

Comment: i am not sure i understand it, `%1` makes sense inside a batch file, not command line, but, if this is the case (batch file), have you tried `sum %*`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are attempting to do, nor is it clear what is failing. Edit your question to better explain what you want, and also show more code and describe how it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myprogramWrapper.cmd

```
@echo off
    myprogram.exe a b c %*
```

Where

```
    myprogram.exe a b c %*
                  ^.^.^......... aditional parameters if needed
                        ^^...... all the parameters passed to batch file
```

Comment: Thanks! Love you so much, guy ^_^

Comment: If I want take parameters from x to y, how can I do (just by index, example from 3 to 5)?

Comment: @user3733276 you have the obvious `myprogram.exe %3 %4 %5`, or you can use `for /f "tokens=3-5" %%a in ("%*") do myprogram.exe %%a %%b %%c`, or can code a loop to concatenate the arguments, or ... it depends of the problem, the type of the arguments, the number of arguments, ....

Comment: It's so complex :( I just want to take, example from c to the last params. Of course, number of params is unlimited!

Answer (score 0):

sum.bat :

```
@echo off
set $total=0
for %%x in (%*) do set /a $total+=%%x
echo %$total%
```

call then :

```
sum.bat 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: No, I don't want to calculate sum for this situation. Just example in order to use my program (sum.exe) and I can include all parameters into my command (sum %1 %2 %3 %4...). But it's very bad because I have to wrote many times. Just I want to use for loop.

Comment: @user3733276 - Your question and your comment are not clear. Please edit your question

Comment: @user3733276 Use: `sum %*`